# Infinite series

Tags: summation

Good afternoon.

I'm brazilian, then sorry by my bad english.
I have a problem with one question about Infinite Series.

I searched for anyone method could help me. I have all constants values (w, y, z, h, a). 
But I don't know what do. Someone can help me? Giving me one way is enough.

Thanks a lot!

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{e^{-\alpha R_n}}{R_n} + \frac{e^{-\alpha R'_n}}{R'_n}\right) \\
R_n &= \sqrt{w^2+y^2+(2nh-z)^2} \\
R'_n &= \sqrt{w^2+y^2+(2nh+z)^2} \\
h &= \text{thickness}
\end{align}

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247325/infinity-series

Comment: @user17762, this question is asked earlier